# Unable to resolve the package modules in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, importerror, setup-project

So my file structure looks something like this:

```
my-project-1
    my-project-1/setup.py
    my-project-1/__init__.py
    my-project-1/src/

      my-project-1/src/__init__.py
      my-project-1/src/sub_proj/

        my-project-1/src/sub_proj/__init__.py
        my-project-1/src/sub_proj/name

          my-project-1/src/sub_proj/name/__init__.py
          my-project-1/src/sub_proj/name/module1.py
          my-project-1/src/sub_proj/name/module2.py

    my-project-1/tests/

      my-project-1/tests/__init__.py
      my-project-1/tests/test.py
```

Inside my `test.py`, I cannot seem to access module1 or module2

I have something like `from src.sub_proj.name.module1 import ClassModule1`

I keep getting `ImportError: No module named`

I have `my-project-1/src/sub_proj/__init__.py` contain `__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)`

In fact, it looks like visual studio cannot even import `pymysql` etc. `test.py` works fine if it's in `my-project-1/src/sub_proj/name/`

Comment: You need to ensure that the module path are in your `$PYTHONPATH` environment variable for them to be discoverable for import, or your current working directory be `sub_proj` when you run the tests. See https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH

Comment: What's a good way to set the $PYTHONPATH for the project?

Comment: It depends on the OS - have a search for 'setting environment variables <your os>' for info.

Comment: Thx, I figured I can set this for my machine but I am wondering what happens if the project was run on a different machine. Since here pythonpath needs to be discoverable for the module in the proj, is there a way to generically set it up in setup.py?

Comment: If you're packaging `my-project-1` with `setup.py` then when it's installed it will be added to the system python path. Then you can reference the sub-module as e.g. `from my-project-1 import sub_proj` (you might want to look at `setup.py` `find_packages()` and associated docs for more info on packaging sub-modules).